# What is the PDF of the sum of N drawings from a PDF

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ with probability density function $f(X)$.  Let $Y$ be the sum of $N$ draws of $X$.  What is the PDF of $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends. If your draws $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ are taken **independently** then the sum $y_n=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$ follows a law with density function $g_n$ such that

$$g_1 =f$$
$$g_n = g_{n-1}*f$$
where $*$ is the convolution operator. So this mean that the PDF $g_n$ is given recursively by:

$$g_1(x)=f(x)$$
$$
g_2(x) = (f*f)(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x-u)f(u)du
$$
$$
g_n(x) = (g_{n-1}*f)(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}g_{n-1}(x-u)f(u)du
$$
You can check this post as well:

[How do you sum PDF's of random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218934/how-do-you-sum-pdfs-of-random-variables)

If your draws are **not taken independently**, you cannot say anything a priori about the law of the sum.

Comment: Thanks Maxime!  I was thinking vaguely [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) but your answer is much more what I was hoping for.

Comment: Also Maxime note that this answer was helpful to me for a more constructive/computation application of this topic [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36630/computing-the-pdf-of-the-sum-of-n-moves-of-an-empirical-pdf-for-usdjpy-1-minute)..